# echo php variable string cut off after ampersand

Tags: php, variables, ampersand

I submit the `s` variable to page.php from an input form on a different page.

The URL has the complete string with the ampersand, when I try to echo the variable, the string is cut off after the ampersand.

form:

```
<form action="page.php" method="get">

<input type="text" name="s" id ="s" />

</form>
```

Variable is:

```
search & search
```

URL:

```
page.php?s=search+%26+search&var2=variable
```

variable echoes as:

```
search
```

I have tried:

```
   echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['s']);
   echo htmlentities($_GET['s']);
   echo urldecode($_GET['s']);
```

Comment: How is the string being encoded?  I think you will experience better results with `search%20%26%20search` (using `%20` to represent spaces instead of `+`)

Comment: I tried typing in page.php?s=search%20%26%20search and it still does not echo the complete variable

Comment: Do you really intend to use GET Method?

Comment: You still need to decode it `echo urldecode($_GET['s']);`

Comment: Ive been testing this with rewritten urls, as page/search+%26+search/ etc just tried with page.php?s=search+%26+search etc and its working

Comment: oh, well then :facepalm:

Comment: page.php?s=search+%26+search&var2=variable, this line meaning you need to echo

$_GET['s'] and $_GET['var2']

Comment: I don't understand.. you not respond any answer, it work for you? Mark the question as anwered to close it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use (at least) 3 differents ways to archieve this:

1 - `urlencode()`: use this function in the place you should generate the url to encode the string for URL format.

2 - use `%26` (without the "+");

3 - Use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`: if you have only one param, you could get all the query_string this way.

UPDATE:

I.E:

```
$url = "page.php?s=".urlencode('search & search')."&var2=".urlencode('variable'); //or urlencode($variable)
```

Then use: urldecode() to parse the differents $_GETs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a code similar to this,

```
<a href="http://localhost/example/page.php?s=search+%26+search">
```

This kind, will result only the `search` after you try to echo it.

Try this way,

```
<a href="http://localhost/example/page.php?s=<?php echo urlencode("search+%26+search") ?>">
```

it's a convenient way to encode a query part of the url.

and also try this one, an example from the official php documentation

```
<?php $query_string = 'foo=' . urlencode($foo) . '&bar=' . urlencode($bar);
      echo '<a href="mycgi?' . htmlentities($query_string) . '">';
?>
```

and for more information, please refer to this.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: I'm just assuming to similar process, and you can come up the same result you are looking in this way too or assign it to a variable

Comment: You dont want to be url encoding `"search+%26+search"` that's already a url encoded string, url encoding `"search & search"` would be ok though

Answer (score 0):

I just tried what you said and the problem doesn't seem to be the encoding of url.

Try this out https://www.google.co.in/?q=search+%26+search , Google searches for `search & search`, there might be a problem on `page.php` where you are trying to echo the variable.

Additionally, to prove that google is not doing anything special i just made two files named index.php and page.php and the result was as expected.

index.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="1.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="s" id="s">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

page.php

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['s'];
?>
```

output:
   `search & search`

Try to debug your code on page.php where you are trying to echo the variable or paste the whole code here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this though I test it locally, here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Problem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="page.php" method="get">
      <input type="text" name="s" id ="s" />
      <input type="text" name="var2" id ="d" />
      <input type="submit" name="name" value="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and page.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['s'])) {
  echo $_GET['s'] .' '. $_GET['var2'];
}
?>
```

when you run it to your browser, it will display two input form and a submit button.

The output will be

`search & search variable`

I try also pasting in the url

`page.php?s=search+%26+search&var2=variable&name=submit`

I result the same

I hope this would help